# ununderstanble ._app.py file on macos

Tags: python, macos

Im deploying a flask app on a remote server

When i run my lint and test locally on my macos I have no problem.

But when i run `tar -cvf project.tar myfolder` then ssh into my server and run `tar -xf /tmp/project.tar -C /mydeployedfolder`, i have hidden .py files that crashes my lint and test.

For example i have ._app.py file with content

```
Mac OS X            2?
                          ATTR
                              ??com.apple.lastuseddate#PScom.macromates.selectionRange
```

This file doesnt appear on my initial foder on my macos (either in finder or if i do cat ._app.py in terminal) . I have tried to tar and untar locally on my mac but no such files appears either.

I have tried to run cmd+shift+. to have hidden files appear but it doesnt work
I have tried to run

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

And it is the same!

I also tried Forklift (a finder replacement where you can show hidden files) and i only have ._DS_Store no hidden py files

I also tried

```
dot_clean mypath
find . -type f -name '._*'
```

But it is the same

How can i do to avoid this or delete the hidden files?

Comment: Does [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them) answer your question?

Comment: thanks it partially does with the commands dot_clean and find but in my cas it only finds ._DS_Store but not my hidden py files!

Comment: The problem is that these files are created when you use some software, including Apple software.

Comment: Such a hassle...makes me want to quit apple! i ended up using find . -type f -name '._*' -delete in my script on the remote server...but i dont understand why i cant access these files on my local machine